# Jquery on click with selector/data

Tags: jquery, onclick

Trying to understand the following syntax in my autocomplete plugin

```
    // Listen for click event on suggestions list:
    container.on('click.autocomplete', suggestionSelector, function () {
        that.select($(this).data('index'));
    });
```

"click.autocomplete" syntax I am confused about, there is no class autocomplete on this page but it still works. what does the ".autocomplete" here refer to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.autocomplete` here isn't a selector, it's a namespace. The selector is contained within your `suggestionSelector` variable. The event being handled is `click` within the `autocomplete` namespace.

See jQuery's [`event.namespace`](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) and [Custom Events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/) documentation.

jQuery's documentation page for [its `on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) states:

> ```
> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
> ```
>
> **events**
> Type: String
> One or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces, such as "click" or "keydown.myPlugin".